# How modify default page library settings via feature?

Tags: publishing-site, provisioning

I've created a custom web publishing template with a custom default page and it actually works! However, I need to customize the default Page Library that is provisioned. Settings include (but aren't limited to) creating views and columns, setting versioning and content type, and attaching a globally reusable workflow.

I figured this should be done via feature so that it's easily updateable in the future, but I'm open to other ideas.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

To [provision a default page](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.nl/2010/07/provision-publishing-pages-in-sandbox.html) you have to use a Module to deploy this page.

Create a new [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms434127.aspx) for example with a name ModDefaultHomePage

Add a default.aspx page to the module. You can add the default of the publishing template which can be found in hte 15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\PUBLISHING\ folder

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>
```

Edit the elements xml to something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ModDefaultHomePage"
          Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;"
          Path="">
    <File Path="ModProjectPortalHomePage\default.aspx"
          Url="default.aspx"
          Type="GhostableInLibrary">
     <Property Name="Title" Value="Welcome" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Welcome Page" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~siteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page" />
   </Module>
</Elements>
```

You have to edit the properties to youre needs

Comment: Hi Remko - Thanks, but I have the default page, I want to modify the Library itself by adding views, etc. Is it possible to create a List Definition for the Page library? Or can the default one that is provisioned be modified after it's created?  THANKS!

Comment: You can provision youre own pages library and deploy youre default page to that library or add a view by code in a feature

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that after my site is created, to create a new page library and overwrite the one that is provisioned by the web template? I'm concerned that since it's a publishing page that I might lose functionality ... I was moreso hoping to just revise the schema of the existing page library if that's possible?

Comment: You can provision youre own views to the pages library by using a feature and add some code at feature activating. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480493.aspx for more information about creating views programmatically

Comment: AH - very helpful. Can I also set the versioning settings using this approach as well? I couldn't find it. I also read that attaching workflow has to be done via feature receiver. Can't I just duplicate the existing Page Library definition and modify it? This seems a bit much when making a template from an ordinary list is so easy!

Comment: Everything can be set.. But I am a bit lost here.. What exactly do you want. Deploy a new libary or change the existing library one time or multiple times.. ?